# Invisible clickable Button in javascript

Tags: javascript

How do I write an invisible clickable Button in javascript?
the line:

```
style = "visibility: hidden"
```

Makes it invisible and also not clickable.

Comment: Don't use `visibility: hidden;`; use `opacity: 0;`

Comment: or display:none; depending on the result you wish

Comment: Do you mean `click()`'able or user click-able? And how/why would someone want to click something they can't see?

Comment: @Bartdude Then it won't be clickable...

Comment: @Ian > Yeh I didn't realize it until I posted... and tested right after :-)

Comment: How can you can set an invisible and the same time click-able button? Dear God!

Comment: @ViniciusLima Using `opacity: 0;`...

Answer (score 1):

`visibility: hidden` hides the element completely, which is why clicking it wouldn't work... Try this on for size.

```
<a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></a>

img{
    opacity: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/brbcoding/VBkRF/

Comment: I want to integrate it in html first <button ..style="opacity:0"..> This way?

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/f7fBW/5/%3a)

```
<input type="button" style="color: transparent; background-color: transparent; border: solid;" onclick="alert('test');">
```

Comment: @adi - "the button has a picture on it " Why if it's invisible?

Comment: @adi do u want to create image button? behind your image there is a invisble button so you click on that button in other words clicking image?

Comment: Image button in HTML:
<input type="image" src="rainbow.gif" name="image" width="60" height="60">

Comment: <td id = "l50" bgcolor = "yellow"> <button type="button" onclick = "twoClicks(5, 0, getToolName, getToolColor)" ><img src = "some img" width ="45" height ="45"/> </button> </td>

Comment: I want if there is no picture, it will be invisible

Comment: @adi Then make the TD clickable and capture the bubble-up event (don't use an inline event handler).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is misguided goal and there are better ways to achieve the desired task - however, the *real* task is only vaguely hinted to in buried comments.

Regardless, see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nxQeC/3/) shows that Color Matching, Transparent Colors, and Opacity:0 will still leave a button element as clickable. (Verified in Chrome, Safari, IE8-10/Standards, FF.)

HTML:

```
<h3>colormatch</h3>
<div class=box>
<button id=b1 onclick=alert(1)>here</button>
</div>

<h3>invisible</h3>
<div class=box>
<button id=b2 onclick=alert(2)>here</button>
</div>

<h3>opacity 0</h3>
<div class=box>
<button id=b3 onclick=alert(3)>here</button>
</div>

<h3>transparent</h3>
<div class=box>
<button id=b4 onclick=alert(4)>here</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#b1 {
    border:none;
    background-color:white;
    color:white;
}
#b2 {
    visibility:hidden;
}
#b3 {
    opacity:0;
}
#b4 {
    border:none;
    background-color:transparent;
    color:transparent;
}
.box {
    border:1px solid red;
    display:inline-block;
}
```